# Get Linkedin Share like and comments

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to get the LinkedIn share(post) like count and comments using the REST API. Please help me if anybody has an idea about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of likes, impressions, comments, shares then you have to hit this URL ->

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/company-statistics
```

provided if you have the id of the company page, then you will get the count of  likes, clicks, impressions, engagement, shares, comments in **month break up wise**.